# Getting a specific value from form api in theme-settings.php

Tags: theming, forms

In my custom theme I am developing, I have a form API setting in `theme-settings.php` that lets a user choose one of two options with a select menu as such:

```
 $form['txtr_settings']['general_settings']['choose_slideshow'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Choose a slideshow'),
        '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('choose_slideshow'),
        '#options' => array(
            'basic' => t('Basic'),
            'fancy' => t('Fancy'),
        ),
    );
```

Then in my theme's `page.tpl.php` I want the value the user has selected to be part of an if else statement.

Right now I have this code which does not seem to work:

```
<?php if (theme_get_setting('choose_slideshow') == 'basic')
            include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/slideshow_alpha.inc");
        else
            include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/slideshow_beta.inc");
  ?>
```

I know if I have a simple single checkbox (checked = yes or '1' I can do something like this:

```
<?php if (theme_get_setting('choose_slideshow') == 1)
```

... but in this case I really want to show the user both options and have them choose one or the other in the select menu.

If I use either option on it's own without the if / else, each works fine so I think it's a question of my `theme_get_setting` value. I am not really sure if this is a Drupal question or a PHP question that I should ask over on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Try using `drupal_get_path('theme', 'theme_name')` in place of `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: @Clive, hmm.. that's not the issue at hand, that part is working fine. I've read documentation and `(dirname(__FILE__)` is certainly acceptable and it works in the case of doing a php include...

Comment: Sorry should have paid more attention there. What's actually in `theme_get_setting('choose_slideshow')` at that point, have you printed it out to the screen?

Comment: well that's darned odd, once I echoed `choose_slideshow` as a simple body class (added some code to template.php) to see what the value was, after that it all started working but I don't know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to really do this was to create variables in template.php using a preprocess function and take some of the logic out of page.tpl.php and to instead use the actual variables created. Based on this, my updated code that's working is:

***template.php***

```
function my_theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
 // create variables for each slideshow
  $variables['slideshow_alpha'] = (theme_get_setting('choose_slideshow') == 'alpha');
  $variables['slideshow_beta'] = (theme_get_setting('choose_slideshow') == 'beta');
}
```

... and then in ***page.tpl.php***

```
 <?php if ($slideshow_alpha): ?>
    <?php require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/slideshow_alpha.inc'; ?>
  <?php else: ?>
    <?php require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/slideshow_beta.inc'; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

It's important to note that what helped me figure much of the code updates out were running it through [PAReview.sh](http://drupal.org/project/pareviewsh). However, I did not want to set up the module and there is an online version which works great but your code needs to be in a git repo on drupal.org so you would have to set up a simple sandbox project to test your code. The online version is on [ventral.org](http://ventral.org/pareview) and it's what drupal.org uses to review projects. The new updated code also does not throw any errors with the code sniffer an the old code did.